# Back to Facebook issue in Swift 2

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I'm trying to sign in with Facebook account and once I login with Facebook I get `< Back to MyAppName` in the status bar of the Facebook app and after it get back automatically to my app the status bar stays with `< Back to Facebook` in the status bar in all ViewControllers it won't disappear. Please where would be my issue?

Comment: Please is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Same problem that I faced in my project

1) Add data in info.plist as shown image

[image]